# Solution to floating point arithmetic for calculator app

Tags: javascript, math

I'm making a calculator app in React and would like a solution to floating point arithmetic without having to round to a fixed number of decimal places or truncating.

Basically, how can I get my calculator app to calculate `0.3 - 0.1` and return `0.2` and not `0.19999999999999998`?

Comment: "*without having to round to a fixed number of decimal places or truncating*" then you'll need to use a library.

Comment: All calculators have a working precision that is 3 to 6 digits longer than the displayed number of digits. Using the available types this would mean rounding to 10-12 digits when displaying numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an arbitrary precision `Decimal` like type to do the calculations. Like this one: [https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/)

Comment: thanks dude! Actually using math.js which is something similar :)